# How to hit an uncollidable (invisible) object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i have a Player and a End object. The End has no Mesh renderer, but it has a Box Collider with a Slippary. So its invisible in the game, i tagged it with "End" and write this Script (in the Player).

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "End")
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
    }
```

But when i hit the invisible object called End, the Player goes ahead. I want to fix this problem because my Player moves on when i finish the game and the coordinates influence the reached points. So it has really to stop (the Playermovement is anytime activated)

Comment: Do any of your 2 `GameObject`s have a `Rigidbody` component ? It's required to call `OnCollisionEnter`.

Comment: no just my Player object. Now i added a rigidbody to my End and i got the problem that the End object falls through the floor.

Comment: Keep your `Rigidbody` component in your player `GameObject`, that's great. In your `if` statement, you may want to add  `Destroy(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());`. If it does not work, something else occurs.

Comment: The best thing to have the rigid body on would be your player, this allows it to "collide" with anything.. then your "end" need only be an empty object with a collider on it, if it "falls" .. just make it either have 0 gravity, or, iskinematic, which ever is most appropriate